# how to get nearby users(from firebase database) from my location using Firestore?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, google-cloud-firestore

in my Firestore database I have users table having users with details and their GeoPoint.

I want to get the users nearby my location in GMSCoordinateBounds by checking the user from database is in my bounds or not.

for any more query comment on the question.

currently I'm doing is but not getting correct results:-

```
    let visibleRegionn = mapView.projection.visibleRegion()
    let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(region: visibleRegionn)
    // we've got what we want, but here are NE and SW points
    let northEast = bounds.northEast
    let southWest = bounds.southWest

    let geopoint1 = GeoPoint(latitude: northEast.latitude, longitude: northEast.longitude)
    let geopoint2 = GeoPoint(latitude: southWest.latitude, longitude: southWest.longitude)


    let docRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("Users")
    let query =
        docRef
        .whereField("locationGeopoint", isLessThanOrEqualTo: geopoint1)
        .whereField("locationGeopoint", isLessThanOrEqualTo: geopoint2)

    query.getDocuments { snapshot, error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error getting documents: \(error)")
        } else {
            for document in snapshot!.documents {
                self.arrListMapData.append(document.data() as NSDictionary)
            }

       }
    }
```

Comment: Can you also share a snapshot of how the user geolocation data looks in the firebase ?

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/J7g4LKc.png

@zenwraight please check this image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think code might be working but you might have a logical error in your code.

```
let visibleRegionn = mapView.projection.visibleRegion()
let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(region: visibleRegionn)
// we've got what we want, but here are NE and SW points
let northEast = bounds.northEast
let southWest = bounds.southWest

let geopoint1 = GeoPoint(latitude: northEast.latitude, longitude: northEast.longitude)
let geopoint2 = GeoPoint(latitude: southWest.latitude, longitude: southWest.longitude)


let docRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("Users")
let query =
    docRef
    .whereField("locationGeopoint", isLessThan: geopoint1)
    .whereField("locationGeopoint", isGreaterThan: geopoint2)

query.getDocuments { snapshot, error in
    if let error = error {
        print("Error getting documents: \(error)")
    } else {
        for document in snapshot!.documents {
            self.arrListMapData.append(document.data() as NSDictionary)
        }

   }
}
```

If you see you had - `isLessThanOrEqualTo` in both places, which actually won't give u the correct results. You need a range so now you want to find all the user around that range so you need to use something like - `isLessThan` and `isGreaterThan`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks that's what I was lacking it's working well now 

Comment: Happy to help @ap00724 :)